# FullCalendar.js event/render to date within a cell

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to find out how to disable the date click within a cell while in the month view. I cannot find it in the documentation on the site. I only see dayRender and disabling the entire cell. I just need the date itself not the cell. I needed selectable to be true for the calendar just not this piece.

[image]

Is there a event/render that I can get to in full calendar to stop this from going to the day view? Thanks for any help that is provided.

Comment: What version of fullcalendar? I tried it with 3.5.1 @ https://jsfiddle.net/8bjg0og7/ and the date is not clickable?

Comment: V3.3.1 I need to have it  selectable: true look at this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8bjg0og7/3/)

Comment: It looks like [navLinks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/navLinks/) is what's causing that to be clickable. I wasn't aware of that functionality previously. Try not including **navlinks: true,** or just omitting it (since default is false)

Comment: That was it man thanks for the help!

Comment: Good deal. If you want navLinks elsewhere but not in month view you can set [view specific options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/) and navLinks can be disabled like that for month view https://jsfiddle.net/8bjg0og7/4/  but the navLinks in week view are still clickable to take you to the day view

Comment: Above and beyond @smcd thank you so much!